# ionic, select input (type number) content on click / focus

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard, focus

In my Ionic app, as you can see, this "select-on-focus" directive doesn't work in iOS...

Here's a video:
https://youtu.be/_bOWGMGesgk

[image: Android]
[image: iOS]

Here's the code:

```
<div class="wrapperFlex withNextButton">
<div class="itemTitle">
    <div class="text">
        {{'paramQuestions.weight' | translate }}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="weightdata" class="itemParameters weightdataclass row">

    <input class="weightinput" type="number" name="userweight" ng-min="{{data.minWeight}}" ng-max="{{data.maxWeight}}" ng-model="data.realWeight" ng-change="updateViewGenVol(data.weightunit, data.userweight, data.BLfactorValue);saveUserWeight()" select-on-focus required></input>
    <div class="weightunitradios">
        <ion-checkbox class="checkboxes checkbox-blueboardline" ng-model="data.weightunit" ng-true-value="'kg'" ng-false-value="'lbs'" ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">kg</ion-checkbox>
        <ion-checkbox class="checkboxes checkbox-blueboardline" ng-model="data.weightunit" ng-true-value="'lbs'" ng-false-value="'kg'" ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">lbs</ion-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

directives.js:

```
.directive('selectOnFocus', function ($timeout) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var focusedElement = null;

          element.on('focus', function () {
              var self = this;
              if (focusedElement != self) {
                  focusedElement = self;
                  $timeout(function () {
                      self.select();
                  }, 10);
              }
          });

          element.on('blur', function () {
              focusedElement = null;
          });
        }
  }
})
```